# what is adobe extension manager cs6/replace.exe

Tags: spyware

When I run Malwarebytes on my laptop it reports that a file called `Replace.exe` in my `Adobe Extension Manager CS6` folder is spyware and wants to remove it. Please can you advise me whether this is a legitimate Adobe file?

Thanks in anticipation,
Nick Drax

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I just got the same flag. Read on [malwarebytes forum](http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=121789) that this is a false positive.